# SQL Query Code Extremely Slow and Fails Often

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I am creating a VBA script that iterates through a large amount of cells (708), and runs 2 SQL queries on each cell.

The issue I am having is that the code takes a considerable amount of time to complete. On top of that, too often the application stops responding and sends a "Not Responding" message.

Below is a section of my code. There is another that is almost exactly the same, but occupies a different range of cells. These both query two databases - totaling to 4 runs of this code.

Code Exerpt:

```
    cn.Open strConnection

    For i = 2 To 433
        strSql = "SELECT Sum(counts) FROM ( SELECT SUM([Time down]) as counts FROM tblDailyDowntimeMach WHERE [Operation] ='" & Cells(i, "B").Value & "' AND [Type of Maintenance] = 'Breakdown' " & Filter & " UNION ALL SELECT SUM([Time down]) as counts FROM tblDailyDowntimeAssy WHERE [Operation] = '" & Cells(i, "B").Value & "' AND [Type of Maintenance] = 'Breakdown'" & Filter & ");"
        Set rs1 = cn.Execute(strSql)

        If IsNull(rs1.Fields(0)) Or rs1.Fields(0) = 0 Then
            GoTo NextRow
        End If

        Cells(i, "D").Value = rs1.Fields(0)

NextRow:
    Next I
```

`filter` is a variable found in another portion of code that is just a date range, nothing special.

If there a more efficient way of accomplishing this task?

Comment: Have you tried to execute directly the query on the database and seen the time taken?

Comment: @Renzo Yes, it almost instantly query'd the database

Comment: Check the table tblDailyDowntimeMach to see if it has the appropriate index(s). I would also load all the data into a recordset and then just rs1.filter to get down to the records you want.

Comment: You really need to leave behind the idea of iterating through records completely. This is a bad thing to do when accesscing any database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a dramatically more efficient way of doing this. Querying the database twice for each row is extremely "chatty". The best way to handle this is to write one or two queries that include the data needed for all rows, return the results to a background tab, and then use a vlookup to match the data you need.

This approach gets rid of all the unnecessary round trips to the database, and as a bonus eliminates the loop in your VBA code, which is also inefficient.

Comment: So, you're saying to collect all data for each `[Operation]`, export it to a background tab, then use VLookUp()... That is considerably easier on the system, I would imagine... I knew the way I was doing this was very slow. Thanks a lot!